# What is the expected date format for the mailchimp export API?

Tags: mailchimp

I'm trying to use the mailchimp export API in order to keep our internal database in sync with a list we've got in mailchimp.

To do this, I am using the mailchimp export API https://apidocs.mailchimp.com/export/1.0/. According to the documentation, you can pass a since parameter, which I have done with success, but only when I pass a date like this `2015-10-01`, but I would like to add a a time factor to it.

I've tried UTC, as well as various other formats.

Does anyone know how to format a date time value for this `since` parameter?